# How to make a “follow the bouncing ball” video?

Tags: software, music

I found easier to teach some score by reading it with the student while playing, and I saw that many people online use this priciple on videos as well:

Do you know how can I make that kind of karaoke-style animations for scores?
Is there a software better suited for it?

For reference, I'll put here a link to a video with the goal I'd like to reach:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tutorial on how to make a bouncing ball karaoke-style lyric follower using After Effects here:

http://aescripts.com/beat-assistant/

The example you give should be simpler, as the ball only bounces on each quarter-note beat -there aren't any lyrics to worry about.

Comment: Hey Tom, could you include more detail about the contents of the link in your own words?  Currently this answer wouldn't give any help if the link were to go dead.